# How Would the Left Side of this Limit be Solved?

Tags: limits, chemistry

I have two equations which represent the ratio of concentration to initial concentration in a chemical reactor, and I need to know what the limit of the left side would be, where when $t$ becomes large. The reaction under study is at steady state conditions. I know the right side is $1/(1+kT)$.

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\left[\frac{2\big(a\ln{(t)}+b-c\ln{(t)}-d\big)\big(1-e^{-t/\tau}\big)}{a\ln{(t)+b}}\right]=\lim_{t\to \infty}\left[\frac{1}{1+k\tau}\left(1-e^{(-1/\tau+k)t}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Just factor $\ln(t)$ from the numerator to get

$$\frac{2 ( a + b/ \ln(t) - c - d/ \ln(t) ) ( 1 - e^{-t / \tau} ) }{ a + b/ \ln(t) } = \frac{[2 ( a - c ) + 2 ( b - d ) / \ln(t) ]( 1 - e^{-t / \tau} ) }{ a + b/ \ln(t) }$$

and note that $\lim_{t \to \infty} 1 / \ln(t) \to 0$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-t / \tau} \to 0$

Answer (score 2):

You can re-write the expression as:

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty }\frac{(2a - 2c) (1-e^{-t/{\tau}})\ln t}{a \ln t + b} + \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty } \frac{(2b-2d)(1-e^{-t/{\tau}})}{a \ln t + b}$$

First limit is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form and could be solved using L'Hopital Rule and the second one goes to zero.